# Git post-recieve hook

Tags: git, sh, githooks

I need help with writing a git post-receive hook.

I need the hook to call external .exe file and pass in parameters.

This is my hook so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

call_external()
{
     # --- Arguments
     oldrev=$(git rev-parse $1)
     newrev=$(git rev-parse $2)
     refname="$3"

     DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"

     $DIR/post-receive.d/External.exe
 }

 # --- Main loop


while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    call_external  $oldrev $newrev $refname 
done
```

It works just fine, except I need to pass some parameters to that exe, and I do not know how to get them from Git.

Thanks to 'phd' heres the update:
I need these parameters per every commit in the push

- Author/Email
- Commit hash
- Commit description
- Branch name

I have no idea how to get this info from GIT.

Edit(2021-04-22) Thanks to 'phd' I was able to put together

```
#!/bin/sh
call_external()
{
    # --- Arguments
    oldrev=$(git rev-parse $1)
    newrev=$(git rev-parse $2)
    refname="$3"
    
    if [ $(git rev-parse --is-bare-repository) = true ]
    then
        REPOSITORY_BASENAME=$(basename "$PWD") 
    else
        REPOSITORY_BASENAME=$(basename $(readlink -nf "$PWD"/..))
    fi
    
    DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
    BRANCH=$refname

    git rev-list "$oldrev..$newrev"|
    while read hash 
    do
    
        COMMIT_HASH=$hash
        AUTHOR_NAME=$(git show --format="%an" -s)
        AUTHOR_EMAIL=$(git show --format="%ae" -s)
        COMMIT_MESSAGE=$(git show --format="%B" -s)
    
        $($DIR/post-receive.d/External.exe "$BRANCH" "$AUTHOR_NAME" "$AUTHOR_EMAIL" "$COMMIT_MESSAGE" "$COMMIT_HASH" "$REPOSITORY_BASENAME")
        
    done
}

 # --- Main loop
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    call_external  $oldrev $newrev $refname 
done
```

Comment: "*Email of the person pushing the commit*" What is **the commit**? The hook is called when updating **a reference**; there could be a hundred of commits between `oldrev` and `newrev`.
"*Commit number #*" What is the number? Commit hash?
"*Decription/comment*" Again, what is this? Commit message?
"*Repository name*" You cannot get this one from git — it doesn't store repository name. You can get the name of the top-level directory from OS, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need these parameters per every commit in the push
>
> ```
> Commit hash
> ```

Run the following loop:

```
git rev-list oldrev..newrev | while read hash; do echo $hash; done
```

Inside the loop `$hash` is the hash of one commit.

> ```
> Author/Email
> ```

That's `git show --format="%an" -s` and `git show --format="%ae" -s`. `%an` means "author's name", `%ae` — "author's email". See the list of placeholders at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#_pretty_formats

> ```
> Commit description
> ```

`git show --format="%B" -s`. That's "full body of the commit message". Can be split into `%s` and `%b`.

> ```
> Branch name
> ```

You don't need it in a loop, you always have it. The post-receive hook is called when updating a reference, the reference is the branch. `refname` in your script.

Let's me combine all this into one loop:

```
git rev-list oldrev..newrev |
while read hash; do
    echo Commit hash: $hash
    echo Author name: git show --format="%an" -s
    echo Author email: git show --format="%ae" -s
    echo Commit message: git show --format="%B" -s
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with finished script.